# Entity Framework Core model with abstract class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a question

I make a Code First Database In `ASP .NET Core 2.1` and `Entity Framework 2.1.1`. For now, im in a planning step and i have one question. I want to have a list of instance of abstract worker's class with method, that will work difrently. My code:

I have a `Farm`:

```
public class Farm
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Farmer> Farmers { get; set; } //my problem
        public virtual List<Driver> Drivers { get; set; } //starts here!
    }
```

In Farm instance i have Workers. I made an `abstract class` for it:

```
public abstract class Worker
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Farm")]
    public int FarmId { get; set; }
    public Farm Farm { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public float UsdPerHour { get; set; }
    public int HoursPerDay { get; set; }
    public int DaysOfWork { get; set; }

    public abstract float CountSalary();
}
```

Worker can be a `Driver` or a `Farmer`:

```
public class Farmer : Worker
{
    public float UsdPerHour = 9;
    public int HoursPerDay = 8;
    public int DaysOfWork = 20; 
    // CountSalary() here, but in diffrent way!
}

public class Driver : Worker
{
    public float UsdPerHour = 10;
    public int HoursPerDay = 7;
    public int DaysOfWork = 18;
    // CountSalary() here, but in diffrent way!
}
```

And my `FarmDbContext`:

```
public class FarmDbContext : DbContext
{
    public FarmDbContext(DbContextOptions<FarmDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Farm> Farms { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Farmer> Farmers { get; set; } // What to do here?
    public DbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; } // Let Farmers and Drivers
                                               // Or Workers?
}
```

In My `farm` i have two kinds of workers. For each "Position" i want to count salary in diffrent way.

What i want to do in code:

```
var Workers = List<Worker>
Workers.Add(New Driver());
Workers.Add(new Farmer()): 

foreach(object o in Workers)
   int salary = o.CountSalary()

// i know that code is wrong, but i describe the way that i want to achive my goal
```

Could you explain me, how to plan my `DbContext` to achive, what i want to? `Farmer` and `Driver` need to have hard-coded values of propertys. When i let `DbContext` like above in my code, i get two tables, `dbo.Drivers` and `dbo.Farmers`. If it will work in a way that i explained above? Is it possible in EF to block that hardcoded value in database and have it in every record of data i tables?

Comment: I think reading [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) will help you

Comment: check this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: @Aldert thats a different version

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Share us what data you have, and what result in the database.

Comment: You could also consider the following: Have your class hierarchy the way you want (immutable domain models and all that). Just before saving, convert it into a simple poco class which is your EF dbset. I did this in the past and it worked better than relying on EF magic. Also you get to keep your domain logic/rules in one place which is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Farmer` and `Driver` classes have no new properties, just some constants for calculations. That is not the Model/Database layer's concern, it's the Services layer job.

**My Suggestion:**

```
public enum WorkerType
{
  Farmer,
  Driver
}
```

Worker Class:

```
public class Worker
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Farm")]
  public int FarmId { get; set; }
  public Farm Farm { get; set; }

  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public WorkerType WorkerType {get; set; } // assuming a worker can only be a Farmer or a Driver
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class FarmDbContext : DbContext
{
    public FarmDbContext(DbContextOptions<FarmDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Farm> Farms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can have a service or extension method that calculates the salary, for example:

```
public static class WorkerExtensions
{
  public static float Salary(this Worker worker)
  {
    switch(worker.WorkerType)
    {
      case WorkerType.Farmer:
        //calculate and return

      case WorkerType.Driver:
        //calculate and return

      default:
        return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can get workers salary:

```
foreach(var worker in Workers)
   var salary = worker.Salary();
```

The problem here is that every time your calculation constants change you need to change code and rebuild/republish. For that you can create a wage info table in your database and get those informations from there, and you can change them whenever you want.

Comment: This is a painful approach against a real-world project as the project and its bussiness needs around `Worker` grows, `switch`es gonna grow.